# How can I implement angularjs in quarkus restAPI

Tags: quarkus-rest-client

Built my first restful application using quarkus. I want to have a frontend which can call these restful services. any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use axios. And integrate with your preferred frontend technology.

[Here is a reference](https://github.com/axios/axios).